# Cannot set a fileIntent for image files of type jpg, png and jpeg

Tags: android, image, filechooser

I'm using the following code:

```
Intent fileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
fileIntent.setType("image/jpg|image/png|image/jpeg"); 
startActivityForResult(fileIntent, REQUEST_FILE);
```

I believe that code should allow me to select any jpg, png or jpeg file, but it doesn't.

On the other hand changing fileIntent.setType("image/jpg|image/png|image/jpeg"); to fileIntent.setType("image/*"); allows to select the file. But it also allows to select another image files I don't want to.

What needs to be corrected in fileIntent.setType("image/jpg|image/png|image/jpeg"); so it allows to choose files of those types and not other ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only specify a single mimetype with `setType()`, instead apply an extra with the key `Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES` with an array of mimetypes:

```
fileIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, Arrays.asList("image/png", "image/jpeg").toArray());
```

I have found that even when providing a list of mimetypes you may still need to apply `intent.fileType("*/*");` to the intent regardless, however, the list of mimetypes will take preference.